# Pandas dataframe replace al non-nan values by a value of specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to transform a dataframe such that all values that are not nan are replaced with the corresponding value of the column 'id'.

Example:
From

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
                   'A': [1, np.nan,0],
                   'B': [0, 0, np.nan],
                   'C': [np.nan, 1, 1]})
```

[image]

to

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
                   'A': ['X', np.nan,'Z'],
                   'B': ['X', 'Y', np.nan],
                   'C': [np.nan, 'Y', 'Z']})
```

[image]

Doing it with looping over column and row indices would probably take very long on large dataframes, so I would prefer a solution using the pandas functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mask and multiplication of the boolean mask as string:

```
m = df.notna()

out = m.mul(df['id'], axis=0).where(m)
```

Or with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

m = df.notna()
out = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m, np.repeat(df['id'].to_numpy()[:,None],
                                         df.shape[1], axis=1),
                            df),
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Another idea with reindexing:

```
out = df[['id']].reindex(columns=df.columns).ffill(axis=1).where(df.notna())
```

Output:

```
  id    A    B    C
0  X    X    X  NaN
1  Y  NaN    Y    Y
2  Z    Z  NaN    Z
```